# How to get two columns in \cvline?

Tags: two-column, moderncv

I want to add certifications to my cv with a column with the names and a second column with the dates, currently I have:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm,headheight=21pt} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\firstname{test}
\familyname{test}
\begin{document}

\section{certifications}
\cvline{Microsoft}{Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Sep 19, 2011\newline Microsoft Word 2010 Expert Sep 14, 2011\newline Microsoft Access 2010 Sep 05, 2011\newline Microsoft PowerPoint 2010 Aug 29, 2011 \newline Microsoft Excel 2010 Expert Aug 09, 2011\newline Microsoft Excel 2010 Jul 14, 2011\newline Microsoft Office Master Specialist Sep 14, 2011}
\cvline{SAP}{test}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

This looks like
[image: t1]
But I want to have two columns so that it looks like:

```
Certification 1                              Date 1
Certification 2                              Date 2
```

So basically two columns, so that there is a space and that it looks better with this alignment into two columns. How can I get this?

Answer (score 1):

```
\cvline{Microsoft}{\begin{tabular}{ l @{\hskip 0.5in} c }
Microsoft SharePoint 2010 & Sep 19, 2011\\
 Microsoft Word 2010 Expert & Sep 14, 2011\\
 Microsoft Access 2010 & Sep 05, 2011\\
Microsoft PowerPoint 2010 & Aug 29, 2011 \\
 Microsoft Excel 2010 Expert & Aug 09, 2011\\
 Microsoft Excel 2010 & Jul 14, 2011\\
 Microsoft Office Master Specialist & Sep 14, 2011\\
\end{tabular}
}
```

gives

[image: t1]

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to simply use `\hfill`. This will move the second 'column' over to the right margin. An advantage of this approach is that you will never have to manually adjust the spacing. However, it does require typing `\hfill` each time.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm,headheight=21pt} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\firstname{test}
\familyname{test}
\begin{document}

\section{certifications}
\cvline{Microsoft}{Microsoft SharePoint 2010 \hfill Sep 19, 2011\newline Microsoft Word 2010 Expert \hfill Sep 14, 2011\newline Microsoft Access 2010 \hfill Sep 05, 2011\newline Microsoft PowerPoint 2010 \hfill Aug 29, 2011 \newline Microsoft Excel 2010 Expert \hfill Aug 09, 2011\newline Microsoft Excel 2010 \hfill Jul 14, 2011\newline Microsoft Office Master Specialist \hfill Sep 14, 2011}
\cvline{SAP}{test}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]