# Column description not centered in moderncv?

Tags: two-column, moderncv

I use [my own solution/workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133399/how-to-get-two-columns-in-cvline) to get a table formatted listings of the certificates in my CV.

I don't like the fact that the description of the \cvline is centered, e.g. I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm,headheight=21pt} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\firstname{C}
\familyname{}
\title{Curriculum vitae}              
\address{}{}  
\photo[128pt]{picture}                        

\begin{document}


\section{certifications}
\cvline{Microsoft}{\begin{tabular}{ l @{\hskip 0.5in} l }
Microsoft SharePoint 2010 & Sep 19, 2011\\
 Microsoft Word 2010 Expert & Sep 14, 2011\\
 Microsoft Access 2010 & Sep 05, 2011\\
Microsoft PowerPoint 2010 & Aug 29, 2011 \\
 Microsoft Excel 2010 Expert & Aug 09, 2011\\
 Microsoft Excel 2010 & Jul 14, 2011\\
&\\
 Microsoft Office Master Specialist & Sep 14, 2011\\
&\\
NAV 2009 Trade \& Inventory & Mar 22, 2012\\
NAV 2009 Manufacturing & Mar 14, 2012\\
NAV 2009 Core Setup and Finance & Mar 08, 2012\\
NAV 2009 Installation \& Configuaration & Oct 04, 2011\\
\end{tabular}
\newline}
\cvline{SAP}{Terp10 SAP ERP}

\end{document}
```

This gives the following output:
[image: t1]

But I do not like that the "Microsoft" is vertically centered.
So I want to have the Microsoft on the same level as the first Microsoft certification. How can I get this? So that it is on the level with the sharepoint certification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\cvline{Microsoft}{\begin{tabular}[t]{ l @{\hskip 0.5in} l }
                                  %%%
```

Comment: THANKS a lot for this nice and short solution! I accept your answer in 7 minutes.